# How to check images for custom characters?

Tags: image-processing, ocr

I have a set of image files that I can identify. Rather than an OCR, I'd like to search only for matches within the set. What's the ideal platform to quickly find matches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) is an advanced computer vision library. It can recognize text blocks, colors, shapes, etc. so it might be of use.

[Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) can be trained to handle languages, but I can't see a reason why you couldn't train it with shapes. Here's a really confusing [training guide](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3).

[ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org/www/) can also be useful. It's pretty hardcore endless parameter chaining, but you can get it to find images. It's not perfect for this application, but it's been done before. The documentation is *insanely huge*, but it's about as complete and illustrated as I could wish for (I'm a frequent user, as it's useful for quick image operations via CLI). Here's the [image comparison documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/).

I would suggest OpenCV, but it's up to you. Good luck!

Comment: I can probably train OCR to recognize the character set I have, but the problem is that I also want it to exclude anything not in that character set.

Comment: I looked at ImageMagick, and it can do that. It can search for images within another image and return the coordinates.

Comment: Tesseract excludes all that isn't in your set. It won't mix Russian and English together. It only does one per run.

Comment: Thanks! Now that I have 15 rep I'll be revisiting some pages I wanted to vote up.